# How do I complete a DependencyProperty of type "Windows" in Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

How do I complete a DependencyProperty of type "Windows" in Xaml?

I have:

```
public Window WindowHandle
        {
            get { return (Window)GetValue(WindowHandleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WindowHandleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowHandleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("WindowHandle", typeof(Window), typeof(CustomBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

What should be entered in the "WindowHandle" property to indicate this window?

```
customBox.WindowHandle = this;//in C#
```

```
<UControl:CustomBox x:Name="customBox" WindowHandle="?"/><!--in xaml-->
```

Comment: `WindowHandle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind to the window, you use `FindAncestor` like :

```
<UControl:CustomBox ...
  WindowHandle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
```